# MyBatis - Perform consecutive delete and insert statements in one query

Tags: mysql, xml, mybatis

Using **MyBatis**, how can one clear a table and insert new values in one query?

**Normal SQL** I am thinking something along the lines of:

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE...
INSERT...;
COMMIT;
```

Is there any way of translating this over to MyBatis within the XML format?

I have thought of making a simple `<sql>` element with the delete and insert commands, but then how would I call this from within the XML? Surely each action must be called from their appropriate tag (`<insert>`, `<delete>`)
?

**For example...**

Say I am wanting to clear a table called Students of all students and populate the same table with new students. I would first clear the table by either `DELETE FROM Students` or `TRUNCATE TABLE Students`, and then I would want to repopulate the table with data etc...

`INSERT INTO Students
    (name,age,class)
VALUES
    (John,12,A),
    (Jim,12,A),
    (Jess,13,C);`

**StudentServiceImpl.java**

```
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {
    Student get(Integer id) { ... };
    Student getByName(String name) { ... };
    Student update(Student student) { ... };
    Student create(Student student) { ... };
    void delete(Integer id) { ... };
    List<Student> list(int offset, int limit, String name) { ... };
}
```

**StudentMapper.java**

```
public interface StudentMapper {
  Student getStudent (Integer id);
  Student getStudent ByName(@Param("name") String name);
  void update(Student student);
  void create(Student student);
  void delete(Integer id);
  List<Student> list(RowBounds rowBounds);
  List<Student> listByName(@Param("name") String name,RowBounds rowBounds);
 }
```

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: @AdriánGarcíaCampos I hope my extension helps?

Answer (score 0):

In theory this is possible using

`<insert id="badWayOfInserting">
    ${SQL}
</insert>`

and passing a string variable called 'SQL' to badWayOfInserting. Altough not recommendable.

The best option is to use transactions of CDI. You would have a method with @Transactional annotation. More or less like this:

```
@Transactional
public void deleteAndInsert(List<Item> listOfItems){
    db.deleteDB();
    db.insertItems(listOfItems);
}
```

CDI transactions are the same as DB ones. It will only commit if everything goes OK.

Comment: Would the @Transactional method be placed within the mapper.java class?

Comment: If you are using MVC, it should go in the Service

Comment: @physicsboy If you post what are your calls from end-to-end, I could tell you where to place it

Comment: I added a bit more info - the classes for Mapper and ServiceImpl

Comment: @Transactional would go in StudentServiceImpl.java. You should create a new void that makes what you want and make it transactional

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll let you know if I come a cropper on anything.

Comment: One question... Would I call this from the XML? Ie, from within an <insert>, <delete> or <sql> tag?

Comment: Using @Transactional?

Comment: Would I have to use the annotation in the xml too?

Comment: No no, only in the header of the void

Comment: Ah I get you now. Would I need to run the method from the XML though?
For example, I have the "create" method defined in my .java class, and in the XML I have <insert id="create" ... > INSERT into ... </insert>